# How to output an empty tuple as part of a function in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm quite new to OCaml, so I apologise for the basic nature of my question.  I've written code to output the head of a list of boolean tuples, as below:

```
let head (lst : (bool * bool) list) : (bool * bool) =
    match lst with
    | (h1, h2) :: tl -> (h1, h2)
    | [] -> ();;
```

However, I get a typing error when handling the case of the empty list, because the empty tuple is of type unit.  Is there anyway I can output an empty tuple as part of the pattern-matching of my function?  I would dislike outputting actual boolean values, since those mean something in the context of my function.  Thanks for the assistance.

Sincerely,
Charles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty" value of type `(bool * bool)`. Every value of that type is a pair of booleans. This is part of what it means to be "strongly typed." So there's no special value you can return for an empty list.

The usual ways to handle this are either to return an option type, `Some (h1, h2)` for a non-empty list and `None` for an empty list; or to raise an exception when the input is an empty list.

The standard function `List.hd` has exactly this same consideration, for example, and it raises an exception when passed an empty list.

```
# List.hd [];;
Exception: Failure "hd".
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I read up on types for OCaml and fixed the issue.